# How to get Coupon from Salesrule table

Tags: magento2

I want to get all applied discount in my cart (include auto discount and manual coupon) is that possible? Previously I was using `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon` but it only get coupon with coupon code and unable to get automatic apply discount (who didn't have coupon code). Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each quote has the `applied_rule_ids` property which determine any cart rule was applied. You can use:

```
$ruleIds = $quote->getAppliedRuleIds();
```

and then you can get this rules from the `Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface`.

[image: Applied rule ids in DB]

Comment: Thanks it works as expected.